# How can I split these boxplots according to a categorical variable?

Tags: r, boxplot

May I ask how can I distribute each of these four to two boxplots which contain the pulse meter of male and female.

```r
islands = read.csv('Data.csv')boxplot(islands$Pulse.meter.First..0m, islands$Pulse.meter.25m, islands$Pulse.meter.Second..0m, islands$Pulse.meter.25m.1)
```

Things like

```r
boxplot(islands$Pulse.meter.25m ~ islands$Sex)
```

can distinguish them, but not working for four of them in the same time.

I currently have a boxplot like this:

[image]

I want a boxplot like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using random data, since you hadn't provided data to download. The key is to first transform the data from the 'wide' format as you currently have the data, with a column per value, to a 'long' format, where all values are in the same column with an additional label column. Then the `interaction` function can be used to create an interaction between the pulse meter type and sex.

```
# example data with random values
islands <- data.frame(Sex = rep(c('Male', 'Female'), 15),
                      Pulse.meter.First..0m = rnorm(30, mean = 2),
                      Pulse.meter.25m = rnorm(30, mean = 1),
                      Pulse.meter.Second..0m = rnorm(30, mean = 3),
                      Pulse.meter.25m.1 = rnorm(30, mean = 4))
                      
# reshape from wide to long
islands_long <- reshape(islands,
                        direction = "long",
                        varying = 2:5,
                        v.names = "value",
                        times = names(islands)[2:5],
                        timevar = 'measurement')

# plot the boxplot, 'cex.axis' decrease the font size so all the x-axis labels are visible
boxplot(value ~ interaction(Sex, measurement), data = islands_long, pars=list(cex.axis=0.5))
```

This generates:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  Gender = sample(c("Male", "Female"), 20, replace = TRUE),
  Pulse.meter.First..0m  = sample(10:60, 20, replace = FALSE),
  Pulse.meter.25m  = sample(30:60, 20, replace = FALSE),
  Pulse.meter.Second..0m = sample(30:60, 20, replace = FALSE),
  Pulse.meter.25m.1  = sample(10:60, 20, replace = FALSE)
)


df <- df %>%
  group_by(Gender) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = Pulse.meter.First..0m:Pulse.meter.25m.1, names_to = "Pulse_meter", values_to = "Count") %>%
  unite("Groups", Gender:Pulse_meter)



df$Groups <- factor(df$Groups, levels=c("Female_Pulse.meter.First..0m", "Male_Pulse.meter.First..0m",
                                        "Female_Pulse.meter.25m","Male_Pulse.meter.25m",
                                        "Female_Pulse.meter.Second..0m","Male_Pulse.meter.Second..0m",
                                        "Female_Pulse.meter.25m.1","Male_Pulse.meter.25m.1"))
 

ggplot(data = df, aes(x= Groups, y = Count)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("(F,0m)","(M,0m)","(F,25m)","(M,25m)", "(F,second_0m)", "(M,second_0m)",
                            "(F,25m.1)","(M,25m.1)")) +
  labs(y="Counts") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]